# How can I call a parameterized constructor inside a for loop.

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

I created a parameterizd constructor area. I used area to initialize the diagonal points. In the int main section, I am not able to call the constructor. Please correct my code and explain the mistakes:

```
int main()
{
 int ab,p,q,r,s,l,m,n,o;
  cout<<"Enter the number of rectangles: ";
  cin>>ab;

  for (int i=0; i<ab; i++)
   {
     cout<<"For rectangle "<<i+1<<endl;
     cout<<"Enter the starting and ending values of the 1st diagonal: ";
     cin>>p>>q>>r>>s;
     cout<<"Enter the starting and ending values of the 2nd diagonal: ";
     cin>>l>>m>>n>>o;
     area obj[i](p,q,r,s,l,m,n,o);
     obj[i].findArea();
     obj[i].display();
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove all occurrences of "[i]" and it will work.

Comment: Unrelated: It's a bit odd to have "area" as a kind of object. If the class represents a rectangle, call it "rectangle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the array `obj` should be used outside the loop I would suggest using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, declared before the loop. Then you have two alternatives:

1. Declare the vector and [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) enough memory (so the data doesn't have to be reallocated when adding new elements), then call [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to add new elements.

   ```
   std::vector<area> obj;
   obj.reserve(ab);
   for (int i=0; i<ab; i++)
   {
       ...
       obj.emplace_back(p,q,r,s,l,m,n,o);
   }
   ```
2. Declare the vector with the correct size (`ab`) and have all elements default constructed, and then copy the actual object into place using simple assignment. This requires that `area` can be default constructed, and possible a copy-assignment or move-assignment operator.

   ```
   std::vector<area> obj{ab};
   for (int i=0; i<ab; i++)
   {
       ...
       obj[i] = area(p,q,r,s,l,m,n,o);
   }
   ```

---

If you *don't* want an array (or a vector), and each object in the loop should just exist in the loop and nothing needs to be used after the loop, just declare the object with the correct arguments to the constructor: See [the answer from Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35365162/440558) for how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Just write :)

```
 area obj(p,q,r,s,l,m,n,o);
 obj.findArea();
 obj.display();
```

As for the statement

```
area obj[i](p,q,r,s,l,m,n,o);
```

then you may not initialize arrays such a way. And it does not make sense to define an array within the loop.